# DocumentDB select document at specific index

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to select a document at a specific index?

I have a document import process, I get a page of items from my data source (250 items at once) I then import these into DocumentDB in concurrently. Assuming I get an error inserting these items into DocumentDB I wont be sure what individual item or items failed. (I could work it out but don't want to). It would be easier to just Upsert all the items from the page again.

The items i'm inserting have an ascending id. So if i query DocumentDB (ordered by id) and select the id at position (count of all Id's - page size) I can start importing from that point forward again.

I know SKIP is not implemented, I want to check if there is another option?

Comment: What's preventing you from knowing which document failed? Proper handling of exceptions should make it extremely easy to see which one(s) if any didn't make it into the DB

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bulk import stored procedure. The sproc creation code below is from [Azure's github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/BulkImport.js). This sproc will report back the number of docs created in the batch and continue trying to create docs in multiple batches if the sproc times out.

Since the sproc is ACID, you will have to retry from the beginning (or the last successful batch) if there are any exceptions thrown.
You could also change the createDocument function to upsertDocument if you just want to retry the entire batch process if any exception is thrown.

```
{
    id: "bulkImportSproc",
    body: function bulkImport(docs) {
        var collection = getContext().getCollection();
        var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();

        // The count of imported docs, also used as current doc index.
        var count = 0;

        // Validate input.
        if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

        var docsLength = docs.length;
        if (docsLength == 0) {
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
            return;
        }

        // Call the CRUD API to create a document.
        tryCreate(docs[count], callback);

        // Note that there are 2 exit conditions:
        // 1) The createDocument request was not accepted.
        //    In this case the callback will not be called, we just call setBody and we are done.
        // 2) The callback was called docs.length times.
        //    In this case all documents were created and we don't need to call tryCreate anymore. Just call setBody and we are done.
        function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
            var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, callback);

            // If the request was accepted, callback will be called.
            // Otherwise report current count back to the client,
            // which will call the script again with remaining set of docs.
            // This condition will happen when this stored procedure has been running too long
            // and is about to get cancelled by the server. This will allow the calling client
            // to resume this batch from the point we got to before isAccepted was set to false
            if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
        }

        // This is called when collection.createDocument is done and the document has been persisted.
        function callback(err, doc, options) {
            if (err) throw err;

            // One more document has been inserted, increment the count.
            count++;

            if (count >= docsLength) {
                // If we have created all documents, we are done. Just set the response.
                getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
            } else {
                // Create next document.
                tryCreate(docs[count], callback);
            }
        }
    }
}
```